# Intuition on direct image and inverse image

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, topos-theory

A geometric morphism $f:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ between toposes is defined as an adjoint pair of functors $f_*:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ and $f_*:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$. The adjunction is $f^*\dashv f_*$, and the functor $f^*$ should preserve limits. We call $f^*$ the inverse image and $f_*$ the direct image.

The standard example is that of sheaves on topological spaces. If $g:X\to Y$ is a continuous function between topological spaces, then one obtains a map $g^{-1}:\mathcal{O}(Y)\to \mathcal{O}(X)$, mapping an open set to its inverse.

We now obtain a functor $g_*$ between toposes $Sh(X)$ and $Sh(Y)$ as follows. Given $F$ a sheaf on $X$ and $U$ an open subset of $Y$, we have the following: $$g_*(F)(U)=F(g^{-1}(U)).$$ It turns out that this functor is the direct image part of the geometric morphism.

However, there is something really counterintuitive by using an *inverse image* operation $g^{-1}$ in defining what is to be our *direct image* functor.

Therefore, coming finally to my question, I am looking for examples of geometric morphisms between toposes in which it is much more clearer why we can think of the functors as direct images and inverse images. Easy examples are encouraged, but more advanced topics are always interesting, too!

Comment: For an example of an analog: in differential geometry, the definition of a "direct image" or pushforward of a tangent vector on $M$ by $f : M \to N$ is in terms of the "inverse image" or pullback operation from $C^\infty$ functions on $N$ to $C^\infty$ functions on $M$.

Comment: The name comes from the fact that, for continuous maps, it is the direct image functor that is covariant as a functor from topological spaces to categories. But it is actually the inverse image functor that is the fundamental one – it is the one that preserves all the structure of a category of sheaves.